# Register ObjectContext with Unity in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, unity-container

Currently, I'm injecting a single instance of a Unit of Work into my service layer objects in my controller:

```
public class OrderController : Controller
{
private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
private IOrderService _recipeService;
private IInventoryService _inventoryService;

public OrderController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IOrderService orderService, IInventoryService inventoryService)
{
    _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    _orderService = orderService;
    _inventoryService = inventoryService
    //Use property injection to apply the Unit of Work context and validation state to our services
    _orderService.Context = _unitOfWork;
    _inventoryService.Context = _unitOfWork;
}
```

Ideally, I would like to remove the UoW context from the controller, and have the UoW's lifetime defined during registration such that the same UoW would be used in the scope of a HTTP request. Each service object that is instantiated during a request would have the same instance UoW injected via Unity. I also want to use async actions in my controller, I'm unsure if there's any impact there.

The description of the HierarchicalLifetimeManager sounds like what I want, but I want to be 110% certain, as I think if I get this wrong I could end up with a debugging nightmare (ref: http://unitymvc3.codeplex.com/)

Would the following registration provide me with the desired behaviour, or should I approach this another way?

```
container.RegisterType<IOrderService, OrderService>();
container.RegisterType<IInventoryService, InventoryService>();
container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
```

Thanks!

Chris

Answer (score 1):

The HierarchicalLifetimeManager only works because of other plubming in the Unity.MVC3 solution.  That LifetimeManager works like the singleton ContainerControlledLifetimeManager, but child containers get a new version of any instances created.

The way the Unity.MVC3 project works with it is that each request makes it own child container stored in HttpRequest.Current.Items (see the `UnityDependencyResolver` in that project), then Disposes of that container at the end of the request (that's the `RequestLifetimeHttpModule`).  Normally, that means any ContainerControlled registrations will be retrieved from the parent, but any Hierarchical reigstrations (like your UoW) are recreated in each child container.  That means you get what you want: a new instance for each request, followed by a Dispose when the request ends.

If you're using the rest of the Unity.MVC3 project, then using the Hierarchical LM works fine.  There are similar ways to achieve the same result with a custom LifetimeManager: see [this thread](http://unity.codeplex.com/discussions/38588) on CodePlex.